# How to check internet availability during single frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, download

In Unity3D, is there any way to instantly check network availability? By "instantly", I mean during a single frame, because lines of code below this check need to work based on network availability.

It all happens during `Start()`. I know I can ping a web page, and get network availability based on any errors occurring during the download of a web page. However, an operation like this takes several seconds whereas I need to know the result immediately, before moving to next line of code in the script.

Comment: No.............

Comment: @Gusman C'mon, there must be way...

Comment: Instantly? Nope.

Comment: You need to do a ping to guarantee a connection.  A cable could be removed and the local PC still thinks the connection is active.  When a connection is closed a message gets sent between clients and an ack occurs.   Simply shutting of a router will not send the close message.  The only other way of ensuring the connection is maintained is to use keep-alive which periodically sends a message with zero bytes to verify connection is still working.  Then you can check if connection is working instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It all happens during `Start()`

Yes, this is possible and can be done in one frame if this is the case. I would have discouraged it so much if this operation is performed every frame in the `Update` function but that's not the case. If this is done in the beginning of the app, that's fine. If you do this while the game is running, you will affect the performace.

> but operation like this take several seconds

This is designed like this in order to avoid blocking the main Thread.

Network operation should be done in a `Thread` or with the `async` methods to avoid blocking the main Thread. This is how most Unity network API such as the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) work. They use `Thread` in the background and then give you coroutine to manage that Thread by yielding/waiting in a coroutine function over frames until the network request completes.

To accomplish this in one frame just use `HttpWebRequest` and provide a server url to check. Most examples uses the `google.com` since that's always online but **make sure** to provide *"User-Agent"* so that the connection is not rejected on mobile devices. Finally, if `HttpStatusCode` is not `200` or if there is an exception then there is a problem, otherwise assume it is connected.

```
bool isOnline()
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
        request.Method = "GET";

        //Make sure Google don't reject you when called on mobile device (Android)
        request.changeSysTemHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 55.0.2883.87 Safari / 537.36");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response == null)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        if (response != null && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Class for the custom `changeSysTemHeader` function used to change the User-Agent:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void changeSysTemHeader(this HttpWebRequest request, string key, string value)
    {
        WebHeaderCollection wHeader = new WebHeaderCollection();
        wHeader[key] = value;

        FieldInfo fildInfo = request.GetType().GetField("webHeaders",
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                   | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                                                   | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField);

        fildInfo.SetValue(request, wHeader);
    }
}
```

Simple usage from the `Start` function done in **one** frame:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(isOnline());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your game is running at reasonable frame rates 30fps or greater then any solution that you can come up with (even pinging the host of your server) will only be valid for instances where the latency of the round trip is less than 1/30th of a second or lower ( roughly 30 ms)

As such it is unrealistic to handle this between frames (except for maybe on local networks)

Instead i would suggest into looking into threading your network based code to decouple it from frames

Answer (score 4):

**Don't do this.**
As long as you do not provide more information of what exactly you are planning, one cannot give you proper answers. 
*This is unsatisfying for both sides.*

**But** what you actually could do:

Open a TCP connection to a web available device like the google.com server.
Once the network state is changed (connected, disconnected, ...) trigger a simple c# event or set a variable like `isOnline = true;`.
This **can** be a way. But it is a bad one.

Comment: Men, you are genius. Thanks.